# Is it possible to create nested generic typeguards in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm in the midst of building out an Angular application, and one of Angular's features is typed response objects on HTTP calls:

> You can structure your HttpClient request to declare the type of the
> response object, to make consuming the output easier and more obvious.
> Specifying the response type acts as a type assertion at compile time.
>
> Specifying the response type is a declaration to TypeScript that it
> should treat your response as being of the given type. This is a
> build-time check and **doesn't guarantee that the server will actually
> respond with an object of this type**. It is up to the server to
> ensure that the type specified by the server API is returned.
>
> To specify the response object type, first define an interface with
> the required properties. **Use an interface** rather than a class,
> **because the response is a plain object that cannot be automatically converted to an instance of a class**.
>
> https://angular.io/guide/http#typed-response

I like the sound of something like that, but would like to have run-time checks as well. Digging through Google, I found that Typescript has "type guards" that, supposedly, serve this function:

> TypeScript allows you to create something called a type guard.
>
> The TypeScript Handbook describes type guards as:
>
> Some expression that performs a runtime check that guarantees the type
> in some scope.
>
> The key here is “a runtime check”. This ensures that the variable is
> the type you’re expecting at the moment your code is executed.
>
> https://rangle.io/blog/how-to-use-typescript-type-guards/

In particular, since `typeof` and `instanceof` don't work as intended for interfaces --which Angular's typed response objects require-- there are "custom type guards" or "user-defined type guards."

> The key features of a custom type guard are:
>
> 1. Returns a type predicate, e.g. variableToCheck is Car
> 2. Contains a logical statement that can accurately determine the type of the given variable, e.g (variableToCheck as
>    Car).turnSteeringWheel !== undefined
>
> https://rangle.io/blog/how-to-use-typescript-type-guards/

Awesome! So I started modeling our back-end's response formats, making some basic type guards, and arrived at something like this:

```
export interface DefaultBase<T> {
    Status: string;
    Code: number;
    StatusMessage: string | undefined;
    Data: T;
    DataHash: number;
    GeneratedAt: string;
}

export function isDefaultBase<T>(
    obj: unknown
    ): obj is DefaultBase<T> {
        
    const test = obj as DefaultBase<T>;
    if(test.Code == undefined) return false;
    if(test.Status == undefined) return false;
    if(test.StatusMessage == undefined) return false;
    if(test.Data == undefined) return false;
    if(test.DataHash == undefined) return false;
    if(test.GeneratedAt == undefined) return false;

    return true;

}

export interface DefaultList<T> {
    Count: number | undefined;
    Items: Array<T>;
}

export function isDefaultList<T>(
  obj: unknown
  ): obj is DefaultList<T> {

    const test = obj as DefaultList<T>;
    if(test.Count == undefined) return false;
    if(test.Items == undefined) return false;
    if(!Array.isArray(test.Items)) return false;

    return true;

}

export interface User {
    FirstName:  string;
    LastName: string;
    Email: string;
}

export function isUser(
    obj: unknown
    ): obj is User {
        
    const test = obj as User;

    if(test.FirstName == undefined) return false;
    if(test.LastName == undefined) return false;
    if(test.Email == undefined) return false;

    return true;

}

// Now I can do something like this to get a list of users:
this.http.get<DefaultBase<DefaultList<User>>>("http://localhost/").subscribe(//etc);

// and now I want to write an interceptor that will check each of the
// relevant types and execute its type guard...
```

But hold up a minute! How can I tell the interceptor to dive into the nested generics and execute their associated type guards? I've spent the last day or two trying to figure out a way to either:

1. Have the interceptor look at the type signature passed in `DefaultBase<DefaultList<User>>` and execute the associated type guards.
2. Have the "top-level" type guard for `DefaultBase<T>` recursively descend
   into its child types and execute their associated guards.

I can't find a way to do either of these things. What I want is to be able to get the types and reason about them, and the second, recursive approach might look something like this:

```
export function isDefaultBase<T>(
    obj: unknown
    ): obj is DefaultBase<T> {
        
    const test = obj as DefaultBase<T>;
    if(test.Code == undefined) return false;
    if(test.Status == undefined) return false;
    if(test.StatusMessage == undefined) return false;
    if(test.Data == undefined) return false;
    if(test.DataHash == undefined) return false;
    if(test.GeneratedAt == undefined) return false;

    // how to associate type and its guard?
    return T?.type_guard(test.Data) ?? true

}

export function isDefaultList<T>(
  obj: unknown
  ): obj is DefaultList<T> {

    const test = obj as DefaultList<T>;
    if(test.Count == undefined) return false;
    if(test.Items == undefined) return false;
    if(!Array.isArray(test.Items)) return false;

    // how to associate type and its guard?
    return T?.type_guard(test.Items[0]) ?? true

}
```

I can of course manually call those type guards. Something like:

```
// some component property...
users: DefaultBase<DefaultList<User>> | undefined;

// some call to an API to set or update the property...
this.http.get<DefaultBase<DefaultList<User>>>("http://localhost/users")
  .subscribe((users:DefaultBase<DefaultList<User>>) => {
    if(isDefaultBase(users) 
      && users?.Data ? isDefaultList(users.Data) : false
      && users?.Data?.Items[0] ? isUser(users.Data.Items[0]) : false) {
      this.users = { ...users};
    } else {
      throw new Error('unexpected response shape!')
    }
  });
```

But the desire is for this to happen automatically, transparently, based on the type signature. The callers shouldn't need to worry about anything other than "we got exactly what we wanted or an exception was thrown." And ultimately, I feel like we shouldn't *need* to manually call the type guards each time because the compiler knows that the interface is associated with the guard, right? Or is that not the case?

Also, if I take this approach, does it really even matter if the `is*` methods are proper type guards? My limited understanding is that typescript does code flow analysis to "hone in on" or "narrow" types within a specific scope, and the special `obj is X` return type syntax is meant to hint at that to the compiler. But if I'm flat-out saying `users` is of type `DefaultBase<DefaultList<User>>` in the `subscribe` call, then I'm not really using the "type guard" feature, am I? Just using the "is this the right shape" logic of the method itself.

Overall, my hunches are that

1. what I'm looking for relies on run-time introspection, or some other feature that Typescript does not or cannot provide.
2. I'm mis-using and/or mis-understanding the purpose of type guards in typescript.
3. There might be a Better Way of doing what I want

But I'm not sure and am hoping for some guidance and/or confirmation of my hunches before I go too far down the wrong path. And, if there's an established way of doing what I'm looking for that I've missed, I'd love to hear about it :)

EDIT:

1. I've thought about this for a few more days, and I'm pretty damn sure this is the case. I don't have the mathematical chops to formally prove it though.
2. My approach doesn't necessarily use type guards in their main purpose of type narrowing, but I still like the idea of labelling functions like this explicitly, so I'm keeping it around.
3. Without an ability to perform run-time analysis of types, I don't see how it's possible to get "associated" information. So... yeah. Putting these guards in place manually within services that others then consume is probably the best course of action. (Though I'm of course still open to others saying "well actually" :P)